# Places Autocomplete API stops updating predictions (iOS)

Tags: ios, autocomplete, google-places-api

I've implemented the Places autocomplete API in my iOS app, using a `UISearchBar` and `UITableView` to house the autocomplete predictions.

The implementation works, but sometimes `-[GMSAutocompleteTableDataSourceDelegate didUpdateAutocompletePredictionsForTableDataSource:]` simply doesn't get called.

The `-[GMSAutocompleteTableDataSourceDelegate didRequestAutocompletePredictionsForTableDataSource:]` is always called when the **GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource** instance is passed the `-[GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource sourceTextHasChanged:]` method.

I would expect either the above update delegate method or the `-[GMSAutocompleteTableDataSourceDelegate tableDataSource: didFailAutocompleteWithError:]` to be called at some point in response to a request, but again, this doesn't seem to always be the case.

Every now and then I just simply stop receiving updates regardless of what gets typed in the search bar, and no delegate method other than the request one gets called. The implementations for the delegate methods:

```
#pragma mark - Autocomplete Table Data Source Delegate
- (void)tableDataSource:(GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource *)tableDataSource
didAutocompleteWithPlace:(GMSPlace *)place {
    NSString *state;
    NSString *stateAbbreviation;
    NSArray *addressComponents = place.addressComponents;
    if (addressComponents) {
        // Type of addressComponent is <GMSAddressComponent *> (absent from public header UPDATE: Is present in 1.12.)
        for (GMSAddressComponent *addressComponent in addressComponents) {
            if ([addressComponent.type isEqualToString:@"administrative_area_level_1"]) {
                state = addressComponent.name;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (state && [[_stateAbbreviations allKeys] containsObject:state]) {
        stateAbbreviation = _stateAbbreviations[state];
    } else {
        stateAbbreviation = @"";
    }
    NSLog(@"City: <%@> State: <%@> Abbr: <%@>", place.name, state, stateAbbreviation);
}

- (void)tableDataSource:(GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource *)tableDataSource
didFailAutocompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
}

- (BOOL)tableDataSource:(GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource *)tableDataSource
didSelectPrediction:(GMSAutocompletePrediction *)prediction {
    NSLog(@"Selected Prediction: <%@>", prediction);

    return YES;
}

- (void)didUpdateAutocompletePredictionsForTableDataSource:
(GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource *)tableDataSource {
    NSLog(@"-[%@ %@] called.", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    // Reload table data.
    [_searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}

- (void)didRequestAutocompletePredictionsForTableDataSource:
(GMSAutocompleteTableDataSource *)tableDataSource {
    NSLog(@"-[%@ %@] called.", self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    // Reload table data.
    [_searchResultsTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Their a limit of requests that you can make on places api check that maybe that's the issue

Comment: @ahmad-ishfaq That was my first thought as well, but that doesn't seem to be what's happening here. Besides, if it were, I would still expect the error delegate method to be invoked.

Comment: If it was a quota problem, then you should definitely get the error delegate called with a GMSPlacesError value. Once this starts happening in your app does it ever work again, or do you have to restart the app?

Comment: @AndrewR The issues persists until the app is terminated and relaunched.